# XPath expression?

Tags: xpath

I want to extract "Date: 2009-09-25, 1:54PM EDT" from this webpage

```
http://auburn.craigslist.org/sha/1392067187.html
```

But I don't understand how to write Xpath expressions for that.

Can anyone help me in that.

I am getting other fields also from this page.

Comment: That page does not seem to be XML compliant, so XPath will probably not be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the HTML through TIDY or some other process to turn it into XHTML?  Or how are you able to execute XPATH against that HTML?

*If the document was well-formed*, then you could probably use the following XPATH:

```
/html/body/hr[1]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

It finds the first HR element in the document, then selects the first text() node following it(which contains the string "Date: 2009-09-25,  1:54PM EDT"

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just run a regexp like the one below?

'Date:\s+([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}.+?\<)'

It seams to be the easiest way. And if you don't want to use pure text you can use XPath 2.0 which has support for regexps (fn:matches).